# How to trigger onclick div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onload

I want to trigger onclick of my div using click event in javascript. But I can be avble to trigger the onclick using jquery. Below is my code.

```
html += '<div id="add_redirect" class="row pl_filter_value margin-bottom-md ' + applied_class + '"onclick="applyFilter( \'' + filter.name + '\', \'category\', \'true\');"><div class="col-xs-12">In Stock Only' + applied_cross+ </div></div>';

$("document").ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#add_redirect").trigger('click');
        },1);
    });
```

if I trigger by using `document.getElementById('add_redirect').click();` the error is telling as Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click') .Thanks in advance

Comment: You have nested single quotes throwing the error but rethink the way you're implementing this. You shouldn't be writing functions  like this (inside strings)

Comment: Missing `+'` after applied_cross

Comment: Please provide a *complete* snippet that demonstrates the issue.  As it is, there are many typos, *possibly* caused by adding to the question and it does not show how you add the `html` variable to your page.   See [mcve].   The error is telling you that, when the code runs, there is no element with id "add_redirect".

Comment: Your edit *still* has a typo and doesn't show how `var html` is added to the page.   There's nothing wrong with the js, as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/opr2ujam/)

Answer (score 0):

Use addEventListener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

```js
html += `
  <div id="add_redirect" class="row pl_filter_value margin-bottom-md + ' ' + ${applied_class}">
    <div class="col-xs-12">In Stock Only + ${applied_cross} </div>
  </div>
`;

$("document").ready(function() {
  const el = document.getElementById("add_redirect");
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // handle onclick here
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.click();
  }, 1);
});
```